# Yup Multi Conditional validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik, yup

I have 3 fields that are not required by default. However, the rule demands that if any of the 3 fields is provided then all 3 will be required.

Example field_1, field_2 & field_3

```
validataionSchema = Yup.object({
  title: Yup.string().max(10, "Max character exceeded").required("This field is required"),
  field_1: Yup.string().max(32, "Max character exceeded"),
  field_2: Yup.string().max(32, "Max character exceeded"),
  field_3: Yup.string().max(32, "Max character exceeded"),
})
```

I have tried

```
validataionSchema = Yup.object({
  title: Yup.string().max(10, "Max character exceeded").required("This field is required"),
  field_1: Yup.string().max(15, "Max character exceeded")
    .when(['field_2', 'field_3'], {
      is: (field_2, field_3) => {
        console.log("* field_2, field_3", field_2, field_3)
        return true
      },
      then: Yup.string().required("This field is required")
    }),
  field_2: Yup.string().max(64, "Max character exceeded")
    .when(['field_1', 'field_3'], {
      is: (field_1, field_3) => {
        console.log("** field_1, field_3", field_1, field_3)
        return true
      },
      then: Yup.string().required("This field is required")
    }),
  field_3: Yup.string().max(64, "Max character exceeded")
    .when(['field_1', 'field_2'], {
      is: (field_1, field_2) => {
        console.log("*** field_1, field_2", field_1, field_2)
        return true
      },
      then: Yup.string().required("This field is required")
    }),
})
```

But am getting `Error: Cyclic dependency, node was:"field_2"`

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of anyone that might be interested in the solution

```
  field_1: Yup.string().max(15, "Max character exceeded")
    .test("field_1", "This field is required as part of Fields details", function(value) {
      let f2 = this.resolve(Yup.ref("field_2"));
      let f3 = this.resolve(Yup.ref("field_3"));
      if ((typeof value === "undefined" && typeof f2 === "undefined" && typeof f3 === "undefined") || typeof value !== "undefined") {
        return true
      }
      return false;
    }),
  field_2: Yup.string().max(64, "Max character exceeded")
    .test("field_2", "This field is required as part of Fields details", function(value) {
      let f1 = this.resolve(Yup.ref("field_1"));
      let f3 = this.resolve(Yup.ref("field_3"))
      if ((typeof value === "undefined" && typeof f1 === "undefined" && typeof f3 === "undefined") || typeof value !== "undefined") {
        return true
      }
      return false;
    }),
  field_3: Yup.string().max(64, "Max character exceeded")
    .test("field_3", "This field is required as part of Fields details", function(value) {
      let f1 = this.resolve(Yup.ref("field_1"));
      let f2 = this.resolve(Yup.ref("field_2"));
      if ((typeof value === "undefined" && typeof f1 === "undefined" && typeof f2 === "undefined") || typeof value !== "undefined") {
        return true
      }
      return false;
    }),
```